# Questions about Travel History

Tags: international-travel, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian by birth. And i live in Nigeria. I want to ask in the case of travel History and I have been to nations like Rwanda, Kenya , etc , Can I use this as travel history in the cause of applying for a Visa or is it a must I apply for Visas to the EU before In order to use it as travel history?

Answer (score 4):

Your travel history is a list of all the countries you have visited. You cannot **decide** what it is, you **have** a travel history. When you are asked, you should tell the truth. Lies will greatly complicate your life and lead to travel bans when they are found out.

For some visa, having *a certain kind* of travel history is useful. If you apply for a visa for France, then a history of recently having been to Belgium, and having left on schedule, will be very helpful. The French will assume that if you were about to overstay, you would have stayed in Belgium.

Of course you don't **have** to have a previous EU visa to get an EU visa. That would make it impossible to get a first EU visa. But the first visa application will get more scrutiny than subsequent ones.

And when you apply for an EU visa, you will have to explain why you travel and what your financial circumstances are. It really helps if your travel history matches this description.

Comment: So you imply, since I live in Africa, I can visit other african nations and use that as history? Is that what you mean sir?

Comment: Going to other countries is traveling. Counties in Africa (except Nigeria, where you live) are "other countries." Traveling from Nigeria to other countries in Africa is traveling. Therefore, you should include going to other countries in Africa in your travel history because it _is_ your travel history.

Comment: @Sam, you do not "use something as" travel history. Either you do have a travel history, or you don't. Visits to Kenya won't be as helpful as visits to Singapore or Australia when it comes to EU visa, but **that is your history.** If you are afraid that your personal situation looks like that of an economic migrant (no good job, no family ties ...) it might make sense to visit "easier" countries like South Africa or Turkey first, to extend your travel history.