# Simple Questions about Travel History

Tags: visas, international-travel, nigerian-citizens, history

Can a visit to Rwanda, Seychelles, and say South Africa be good enough to make a travel History for US and Canada visa applications. I am Nigerian, and I have a job and I am in Civil Union.

Comment: In your [previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149123/questions-about-travel-history) you stated you have been to Rwanda. You might get more information if you post the **full reasons** why you had a visa refusal, or refusals.

Comment: Please write a more informative title

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be confused about the intent of the "Travel History" question.

This question is a factual statement of where you have traveled.  There is no minimum requirement for the number of countries you have traveled to, nor any specific requirements for such countries.  If you have visited zero countries other than your home country, then that is the correct answer to the question.  If you have visited 10 other countries, then you should list those 10 countries.

In general, the number or even the specific countries will not have an impact on your application, however there can be exceptions if the consulate staff believe there is some form of pattern to your travels which might prevent you being eligible for a visa.

Comment: yes i am very confused, I have to be honest. I was recently denied visa because of this Travel history issue. Hence i wanted to visit some African nations closer to Nigeria e.g. Ghana , Benin, Seychelles and then Rwanda. just making sure i do not get refused the second time.

Comment: @Sam More important for the application of a Schengen Visa is that you prove that you have a good reasons to return to your home country. The travel history is only one aspect that proves that you have done so in the past

Comment: @MarkJohnson So I can have as many as they are , be it anywhere outside my home country? Does not matter maybe its Africa or some other place , Right?

Comment: @Sam Yes, if it is the truth. Never 'make' anything up.

Comment: @Sam What tends to matter most when applying for US and Canada (and others such as Schengen, UK) is that the travel history shows trips to countries with equivalent immigration regimes. For example if the countries you visit have fairly lax rules for visitors, your travel history may not have as much weight from an immigration risk perspective compared with a history including visits to countries with stronger requirements.